# Firebase firestore functions: no data returned

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have tried over and over to load data from my firestore database from a function.  However, the firestore never returns any data, and nothing is logged in the 'showAll' method.  I have whittled this down to the simplest form.  All I am doing is looping through the data and printing it to the log.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.migrate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log('running migrate');
    admin.firestore().collection('rooms').get().then(collection => {
      // collections.docs has no elements
      console.log('root collections', collection.docs);
      collection.docs.forEach(doc => {
        // therefore this is never called
        console.log('doc in root collection', doc);
      });
   })
   .then(obj => res.send('success'))
   .catch(error => {console.log(error); res.sendStatus(500);});
});
```

There is data in the firestore:
[image: picture of data in cloud firestore]

I feel like I am missing something obvious.  I have other functions that run on triggers, and they work fine.  This is the only function where I am not being passed in a document ref, and it is the only one not getting data.

Is there some other path I should use to find data?  Am I missing an initialization piece? (I am running this on the firebase server as the only way I could get this to run locally is to include a service account in code, which I do not want to do).  Should I be using some other way into my firestore other than 'admin.firestore()'?

thanks for any help!

Comment: This question is just about understanding asynchronous methods in javascript.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear on the ask.  The issue here isn't that I am expecting any results.  The 'showAll()' method executes but there is never any data logged.

Comment: But I don't see the chain of calls from `showAll` to `migrate` http handler. Where do you call `showAll` method and how it looks like?

Comment: @ZuzEL It used to be from migrate to showAll.  Now, I just put the code in the same method to remove some of the confusion.   I should really quit editing the question.  :(

The part that doesn't work that I expect to work is:
admin.firestore().collection('rooms').get().then(collection => {
      // collections.docs has no elements
      console.log('root collections', collection.docs);
......

nothing is returned from that call even though i have a collection in the root of the DB called "rooms" as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your response to the client only after all the asynchronous work is complete.  Right now, you're sending the response immediately without waiting for the query to complete.  When you return your response from an HTTP type function, Cloud Functions will terminate and clean up any async work, even if it's not done.

A minimal version of your function will look like this;

```
exports.migrate = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log('running migrate');
    admin.firestore().collection('rooms').get()
    .then(collection => {
        collection.docs.forEach(doc => {
            console.log('doc in root collection', doc);
        });
        res.send('success');
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

Note that `res.send` is called inside the callback, after the query is complete.

If you want to move your query to another function, that function will have to return a promise, and the caller will have to wait on it to send the response at the right time.

In short, be sure to fully understand how promises work, otherwise your function can fail in mysterious ways.

Comment: I updated my example to more accurately reflect the issue.  The problem is nothing is logged because the collection('rooms') does not return any data.